# Authentication component in Cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp, authentication

seems like the documentation about Authentication in CakePHP 3.0 is not related to 3.0 (some pieces of codes don't work, indeed). Is that right?

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

Comment: I think ver 3.0 is still in development, not yet stable release, so don't expect docs to be sorted out just yet.

Comment: so.. how can I set Auth up?

Comment: with 2.4 everything is ok. i was trying to fiddle with 3.0-dev2. any advice about Auth?

Comment: The best advice would be to wait for a beta release.

Answer (score 0):

If You can see on paragraph [Controller & components](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/wiki/3.0-Roadmap#controller--components) of roadmap CakePHP 3.0 is in the process of writing.

Comment: you're right! auth component is still unchecked ;)
thanks for your link. i missed it.